# adding a nic to a linux system

Tags: linux, networking, installation, network-adapter

I've just bought an HP NC360T Dual Port Gigabit Ethernet Adapter PCI-E for use in a linux box.

I can't seem to see the device on the system.  I've used the lspci command to display a list of items on the pci bus.  This also display PCIe adapters, right?

I can see two network controllers (these are already built in and I can access them - they're eth0 and wlan0.)

But I can't see my new card on there.  I can see the network activity light flashing when I plug into a switch, so I'm assuming the card isn't dead.  I guess I could test it on a windows box as it tends to have better plug and play.

My linux distro is zentyal.

are there any other commands I might try to query the system for the device?

thanks

Comment: Support for the NIC adapter should be compiled in the kernel or be loaded as a kernel module. Probably it is neither compiled in nor you have module loaded in. Check if you have file `/proc/config.gz` - this is running kernel configuration. We can check if your kernel was configured to support this NIC. What is the brand and model of your NIC adapter?

Comment: brand is HP, model is NC360T dual port gigabit adapter.  just checking now for that /proc/config.gz file..

Comment: no, /proc/config.gz is not available.

Comment: I see. I just reread your post... You said you used `lspci` - do you see the NIC there in the output of `lspci`? It should be there regardless of kernel support. Also, just to make sure - issue a command `ifconfig -a` - it should display all available interfaces including deactivated ones

Comment: I can't see the card in lspci output.  I also can't see any entry with ifconfig -a - although I do see eth0 and wlan0, which are already in the system and in use.

Comment: OK. Than we should dig into hardware level, because `lspci` is the low (probably even _lowest_) level discovery tool which queries PCI bus to find out what is connected to it. Check if this PCI slot is enabled in the BIOS, also I would try to put in this PCI slot another device which works for sure - to see that slot itself is operational.

Comment: You need to use the `dmesg` command to look for what the driver did during startup.  Perhaps the driver probe or initialization failed and reported something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled a few things and this is what I came up with:

Your card has an Intel 82571EB chipset. [Ubuntu Forum Post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2007-February/108044.html)

The Intel 82571EB chipset needs the e1000e kernel module [Gentoo Forum Post](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-929084-view-next.html?sid=27dbe03cb352b424ea1b0fe89a2158d2)

Therefore you need to load the e1000e module. If you have the module, try as root

```
modprobe e1000e
```

If you get something like

```
# modprobe e1000e
modprobe: FATAL: Module e1000e not found.
```

Then you don't have the module. You will either need to install the module or recompile your kernel to include it. Apparently zentyal uses apt as a package manager. Try searching for the module doing something like

```
apt-cache search e1000e
```

However I'm not too familiar with apt nor zentyal so I don't know if/where you will find that kernel module. However the e1000e kernel module is what you are after.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I've just inserted the module now and I'm rebooting.  Hopefully I'll see something in lspci output this time :)

Comment: :/  well, I've managed to add the e1000e module at boot time, but I'm still not seeing my hardware.  I'm wondering if it could possibly be a hardware fault with my pcie slot...

Comment: seems like this story had a happy ending after all.  a bios option (force PCIe graphics) - when turned on - solved it - my card is now visible!  Thanks for your help!